# Dúvida sobre o método reduce em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Peguei esse pequeno código de um material da internet para imprimir quantas vezes um numero se repete no array, porém não consegui entender direito o que foi feito, principalmente com esse `if` e com o `acumulado[atual]`.

Quem puder me explicar melhor esse trecho de código agradeço e positivo a resposta.

```
const numeros = [7, 61, 36, 2, 17, 61, 114, 20, 2, 17, 7, 61]
const quantasVezesRepetiu = (acumulado, atual) => {
  if(!acumulado[atual]){
    acumulado[atual] = 0
  }
  acumulado[atual] += 1
  return acumulado
}
const vezes = numeros.reduce(quantasVezesRepetiu, {})
console.log(vezes)
```

Comment: O codico está errado, a variável `numero` não foi definida.

Comment: Na verdade o código está certo, @MariaEduarda...

Comment: @MariaEduarda ja editei, tinha feito a publicação sem o array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devemos entender, primeiramente, que o `Array.prototype.reduce` trabalha sobre um array. No caso, o array que será reduzido é o próprio array sob o qual chamamos o método `reduce`. Além do array (que é o "argumento" `this`), `reduce` requer uma função redutora e aceita um valor inicial.

No exemplo que tratamso nesta resposta, chamamos `reduce` assim:

> ```
> const result = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1].reduce(countReducer, {});
> ```

Então:

- O array a ser reduzido será `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]` ("argumento" `this`).
- A função redutora é `countReducer` (primeiro argumento do método).
- O valor inicial é `{}` (segundo argumento do método).

Com isso, para *cada* elemento do array `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]`, a função redutora que passarmos será chamada. O truque para "entender" é saber que o valor que a função redutora retornar será utilizado como o parâmetro `accumulator` para a iteração seguinte. Por isso é importante definir um acumulador inicial na maioria dos casos.

- Leia a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), que tem um exemplo explicando passo a passo.

É importante observar que se você não definir acumulador inicial, o primeiro elemento do array será utilizado como tal. No entanto, nessa situação, de acordo com a lógica do que queremos fazer, isso não é desejável.

---

Indo, agora, ao código completo, temos:

```js
function countReducer(accumulator, current) {
  // Caso o item da iteração atual ainda não tenha sido contabilizado.
  if (!accumulator[current]) {
    // Inicializamos o contador para o item da iteração atual como 0:
    accumulator[current] = 0;
  }

  // Incrementamos o contador para o item da iteração atual:
  accumulator[current] += 1;

  // Retornamos o acumulador para as próximas iterações:
  return accumulator;
}

const result = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1].reduce(countReducer, {});
console.log(result);
```

```
1  | function countReducer(accumulator, current) {
2  |   // Caso o item da iteração atual ainda não tenha sido contabilizado.
3  |   if (!accumulator[current]) {
4  |     // Inicializamos o contador para o item da iteração atual como 0:
5  |     accumulator[current] = 0;
6  |   }
7  |
8  |   // Incrementamos o contador para o item da iteração atual:
9  |   accumulator[current] += 1;
10 |
11 |   // Retornamos o acumulador para as próximas iterações:
12 |   return accumulator;
13 | }
14 |
////                                                        ↓↓
15 | const result = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1].reduce(countReducer, {});
16 | console.log(result);
```

Vamos entender o que queremos que aconteça para depois entender o código acima, linha a linha.

Supondo que temos um array como `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]`, queremos retornar um objeto com a quantidade de cada elemento do array, assim:

```
{
  1: 3,
  2: 2,
  3: 1
}
```

E como o `reduce` nos ajudará a chegar nisso?

Partindo da primeira linha a ser executada (`15`), onde *invocamos* o método `reduce`, note que passamos, como valor inicial, um objeto literal "vazio" (`{}`). Esse é o nosso objeto `accumulator`, só que ele ainda se encontra "vazio"!

A partir disso, o `reduce` chamará a função `countReducer` *para cada* elemento do array. De modo que o parâmetro `accumulator` será dado pelo que a função `countReducer` retornar na iteração anterior (exceto na *primeira* iteração, na qual `accumulator` é o objeto vazio que definimos no segundo argumento do método).

Partindo da primeira iteração (na qual `{}` ainda está vazio), precisamos ir adicionando os elementos com as respectivas contagens. Para isso, utilizamos a notação `accumulator[current]`. Essa é a [notação de colchetes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_colchete) para acesso em objetos no JavaScript.

No caso específico da primeira iteração, por exemplo, o `accumulator` ainda estará vazio. Nesse caso, como `current` corresponde ao primeiro elemento do array, o que estamos fazendo é, isto:

```
accumulator[current]
```

É o mesmo que:

```
accumulator[1]
```

Isso significa que estamos tentando acessar a propriedade `1` no objeto `accumulator`. No caso da *primeira* iteração, essa propriedade ainda não estará definida, portanto, a expressão `accumulator[current]` (na primeira iteração) retornará `undefined`.

Nesse caso, como o contador ainda não foi definido, precisamos criar um jeito de definir o contador como `0` para que possamos iniciar a contagem para o elemento em questão. É isso que o `if` (linhas 3~6) está fazendo. Ele verifica se o contador referente ao elemento (`current`) atual ainda não foi definido e, se realmente não tiver sido definido, *seta* o contador do elemento atual para `0`.

Desse modo, na linha 9 podemos *incrementar* a contagem referente ao elemento atual. Novamente temos a expressão `accumulator[current]`, que, basicamente, significa:

> Acesse, no acumulador, a propriedade cuja chave é (dinamicamente) `current` e incremente 1, indicando que percorremos esse item uma vez.

Essa mesma lógica é processada para cada elemento do array.

Comment: Luiz, muito obrigado pela resposta, esclareceu algumas coisas, mas essa expressão 'accumulator[current]' ainda está confusa para mim, ainda não consegui entender qual valor essa expressão está pegando, e essa na verdade era minha principal duvida.

Comment: @danielhcr22, tentei editar a parte final da resposta para explicar um pouco melhor. Agora deu para entender? :-)

Comment: Luiz, agradeço a sua resposta, mas vou levar um tempo ainda para assimilar isso, lendo sua resposta e mais alguns outros materiais percebi que ainda me resta algumas duvidas sobre objetos, vou rever esse assunto melhor e retornar aqui para ler sua resposta, assim ficará bem mais fluido o entendimento, obrigado!